# How to subscribe to update data in Item LazyColumn when using task list

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel, lazycolumn

I'm fetching a list of images from the server and displaying them in a `LazyColumn`. However, the images can be quite large, up to 5md, and I need to show them in their entirety.

*I can't use Coil because the server, powered by Amazon, generates a unique URL.*

To address this, I cache the images in the device's memory and display them. Initially, I considered loading them all at once by calling the file download function in each LaunchedEffect within every LazyColumn item, and returning the path to the image as a callback. However, I encountered an error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 16-byte allocation with 199,440 free bytes and 194KB until OOM, target footprint 201326592, growth limit 201326592; giving up on allocation because <1% of heap free after GC.
```

So, I devised an alternative approach, downloading images sequentially in a coroutine. This helped me eliminate the error and device freezing issues.

**However, I'm unsure how to correctly subscribe to updates** in my ItemPhoto so that it knows when an image with ID "1" has been cached and should be displayed within the LazyColumn.

Here's my code. I have written it in one file and it completely shows the functionality of what will be on the screenshot.

```
    @HiltViewModel
class BigFileViewModel  @Inject constructor(
    val serviceApi : ServiceApi
) : ViewModel(){
    private val channel = Channel<DownloadImage>()
    var loadedImagesList  = mutableStateOf<List<DownloadImage>?>(null)
        private set
    init{
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
            for (operation in channel) {
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).async {
                    serviceApi.downloadFileLink(operation.imageLink).collect{response->
                        if(response is NetworkResponse.Success){
                            updateItem(DownloadImage(operation.itemId, response.data))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun updateItem(downloadImage: DownloadImage) {
        loadedImagesList .value = loadedImagesList .value.orEmpty() + downloadImage
    }
    fun downloadPhoto(itemId : Int, url : String){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            channel.send(DownloadImage(itemId, url))
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun BigFileList(bigFileViewModel : BigFileViewModel = hiltViewModel()){
    LazyColumn(content = {
        items(1){
            FlowRowItem(bigFileViewModel)
        }
    })
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalLayoutApi::class)
@Composable
fun FlowRowItem( bigFileViewModel : BigFileViewModel){

    FlowRow(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(8.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start
    ) {
        for(item in 0..23){
            ItemPhoto((0..10000).random(), imageList.random(), bigFileViewModel)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ItemPhoto(itemId : Int, setLink : String, bigFileViewModel : BigFileViewModel){
    val link = remember { mutableStateOf<String?>( null ) }
    val updateList by bigFileViewModel.loadedImagesList

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit, block = {
        bigFileViewModel.downloadPhoto(itemId, setLink)
    })

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = updateList, block = {
        updateList?.forEach {item->
            if(item.itemId == itemId){
                link.value = item.imageLink
            }
        }
    })

    link.value?.let {url->
        Image(
            painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
                url,
                filterQuality = FilterQuality.None,
            ),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = itemModifier2,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
        )
    } ?: run {
        Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
           Column(
               modifier = itemModifier2,
               verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(5.dp, Alignment.Top),
               horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
           ) {
               CircularProgressIndicator()
               Text("$itemId")
           }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]